# How can I get the specific strings in column value

Tags: python, pandas

what I want to do is delete certain parts of a string and take the only near of AcoS and insert it into a new column.

```
import pandas as pd


data = [{"Campaign" : "Sf l Spy l Branded l ACoS 20 l Manual NX"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.insert(1,"targetAcos", 0)
df["targetAcos"] = df["Campaign"].str.replace(r' l ACoS \(.*)\l', r'\1', regex=True)

print(df["targetAcos"])
```

But I guess I am kinda bad at this, I couldn't make it correctly so I hope you guys can explain how can you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Pandas function you want to be using here is `str.extract`:

```py
df["targetAcos"] = df["Campaign"].str.extract(r'\bl ACoS (\d+) l')
```

Or perhaps a more generic regex would be:

```py
df["targetAcos"] = df["Campaign"].str.extract(r'\bACoS (\d+)\b')
```